# Recommendations for getting started with WiX?

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, isapi

I found a [WiX Tutorial](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/), but it's really long-winded and seems like more than I wanted.  What's the best way to get started quickly?

My end goal is nothing really complicated:  an installer that installs an ISAPI filter.

Comment: Just adding this link for reference. I find this the quickest crash course: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/105638/A-quick-introduction-Create-an-MSI-installer-with. And perhaps also read about [**the history of wix**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12101548/129130) to better understand where the technology is coming from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used that same tutorial a couple years ago when I needed to learn WiX. MSI (and therefore WiX) are incredibly complex, you'll need to invest some time to get it right.

If you have Visual Studio, I highly recommend getting Votive (which, I think, comes bundled in WiX v3 now). It'll set up VS to recognize the WiX XML schema and make hand-editing XML files much easier.

Answer (score 12):

When you install the WIX 3.0 toolset, it comes with a manual. It is installed to `C:\Program Files\Windows Installer XML v3\doc\wix.chm` and is linked in the start menu.

This is not just a dry reference manual. It contains a lot of introductory material such as the "*Authoring your first .wxs file*" and "*How To: Add a File To Your Installer*".

The manual also links to the tutorial you mention and some audio-visual material in the "*Getting Started Learning Wix*" topic.

The wix3 manual is also available online [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/).

Comment: This is how I got started and I found it quite helpful for the simple aspects of my installer. I suggest using this file and if you need to get more complicated there are resources available on the wixwiki mentioned above that I also found useful.

Answer (score 7):

That tutorial is actually probably the best that's out there right now - WiX and Windows Installer technology is a bit "baroque" and involved....

If you want to whip up just a quick'n'easy installer, maybe this will be good enough for you?

[Wix# (WixSharp) - managed interface for WiX](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/WixSharpArticle.aspx)

It's like writing C# - and it gets compiled to WiX - quite nifty.

It can't do everything - but maybe for your simple install, it's good enough - or at least it could give you a skeleton to build upon.

Marc

Comment: Thankas Marc.  I find the Wix learning curve to be a wall.

Comment: Part of the wall is not WiX so much as Windows Installer itself. WiX just provides a maintainable, clear way to create the MSI, but it doesn't necessarily hide us from all the complexities and gotchas of Windows Installer.

Answer (score 6):

The tutorial is probably the simplest way to learn how to author an installer using WiX, but there are samples on the [wixwiki](https://web.archive.org/web/20080703102209/http://www.wixwiki.com/index.php?title=Main_Page) site that you may be able to adapt without needing to learn everything involved in writing an installer from nothing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a basic introduction [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/WixTutorial.aspx) on the CodeProject. The second part, which includes getting started with the GUI and features, is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/WixTutorial2.aspx).

I found these to be a great place to start before delving into the details in the (much more complete) tutorial you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

WiX and Windows Installer will definitely be more than you expect if you come from a Visual Studio setup project background, because it offers perhaps 20% of the functionality of Windows Installer (and WiX) and uses functions like Service Installer classes which are definitely not necessary in Windows Installer.

This is useful too - the MSI to WiX series of blogs, start here:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/01/25/from-msi-to-wix-part-1.aspx